# Why is my XML file empty after generating with XML::LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

This is my perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::LibXML;
$doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new;

my $root = $doc->createElement("log");
$root -> setAttribute("time" => "now");

my $tag = $doc->createElement("greeting");

my $value = "hello";
$tag -> appendTextNode($value);
$root -> appendChild($tag);

$doc -> toFile('test.xml');
```

However, the output file test.xml only consists of this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

I assume that this means that the xml file is created but nothing is added to it. I don't get any errors though, so I don't know where to look. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, you should start using `strict` and `warnings`. You didn't have `strict` in your last question as well.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks for the tip. I took your advice (and added a lot of variable declarations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the element you created to the document:

```
$doc->setDocumentElement($root);
```